# How do you set the ansible python3 module directory?

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

How does one get Ansible to read the correct path when installing a pip package with python3?

I have a docker file which installs Ansible and the hvac package, which is needed to interact with hashicorp vault.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

WORKDIR /ansible

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
        curl \
        git \
        python3 \
        bash \
        python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org \
        ansible \
        ansible-lint \
        hvac  \
    && ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3 \
    && ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python
```

When I run the playbook the error tells me that Ansible can't load the package (hvac)

playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  vars_files:
    - ../defaults/all.yml

- name: install hvac pip package
  delegate_to: localhost
  pip:
    name: hvac
    state: present

- name: Create directories
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.file:
    dest: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: directory
    owner: vault
    group: vault
    mode: "{{ item.mode }}"
  with_items:
    - path: "{{ vault_config_file_path }}"
      mode: "0777"
    - path: "{{ vault_token_path }}"
      mode: "0777"

- name: Generate a secret-id for the given approle
  community.hashi_vault.vault_write:
    url: https://vault.emirates.group
    namespace: "{{ namespace }}"
    path: "{{ approle_path }}"
    token: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'VAULT_TOKEN') }}"
  register: secret_id
  no_log: false
  delegate_to: localhost


- name: Set fact the AppRole SecretID
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    secret_id: "{{ secret_id.data.data.secret_id }}"
  no_log: true
```

error:

```
"msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (hvac) on master-135-1b3z3's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"
```

I have checked the pip install folder in the image and it doesn't match the Ansible python module folder.

Hvac location:

```
root@b5dcd7169e39:/ansible# pip show hvac
Name: hvac
Version: 0.11.2
Summary: HashiCorp Vault API client
Home-page: https://github.com/hvac/hvac
Author: Ian Unruh <ianunruh@gmail.com>, Jeffrey Hogan <jeff.hogan1@gmail.com>
Author-email: admin@python-hvac.org
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
root@b5dcd7169e39:/ansible#
```

and I can load the module in python3 in the container without error.... so that part if fine

```
root@b5dcd7169e39:/ansible# python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hvac
>>>
```

but, I am wondering how to change this path "ansible python module location"?

```
root@b5dcd7169e39:/srv/ansible#  ansible-playbook --version -e "ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3"
ansible-playbook [core 2.15.3]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
root@b5dcd7169e39:/srv/ansible#
```

What variable can I use to correct Ansible and put it in the right path?

I tried setting the library variable in the `ansible.cfg` file, but it still wasn't able to find the module installed with pip.

ansible.cfg file:

```ini
[defaults]
inventory = inventory/inventory.ini
host_key_checking = false
interpreter_python = auto
timeout = 60
ansible_parent_role_paths = roles
library = /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
```

I tried looking in the Ansible documentation for this, but to no avail... Has anyone had to do this before?